# Detecting active tab with js

Tags: javascript, tabs

I want to detect which nav-tab is selected and include a different page depending on the selection. I searched thru Google and found what should be a solution here on stackoverflow. However it doesn't do what (I think) it should do. I have gone thru the code line-by-line but can't see what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code snippet:

```
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#level-one" data-toggle="tab"> One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level-two" data-toggle="tab"> Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level-three" data-toggle="tab"> Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level-four" data-toggle="tab"> Four</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <script>
                         tabValue = $(".nav-tabs .active > a").attr("href");
                    </script>
                    <!--write to console to see what is happening.-->
                    <button onclick="console.log(tabValue)">Click</button>
```

I am trying to grab the href of the active tab - I will then do something based on the active tab. However no matter which tab is active **'#level-one'** is always returned. When I hover over the tab the bottom of the screen displays "mysite.com/mypage.php#level_*" so this is possible = I must be doing something wrong! Can anybody help?
Thanks.

Comment: http://codepen.io/samkeddy/pen/MjNPvO seems to work for me

Comment: Thanks, but this only returns '#level-two' no matter what is clicked. It doesn't change on selecting one, three or four.

Comment: It's doing it based on the .active class you put in your html. I moved it to the second element to show it works. In order for it to show something different, the html would need to change. By selecting do you mean clicking on those elements? If so I don't understand why .active exists, and it should be removed from the html and jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence. I understand that changing the 'active' does change the returned href. If I remove 'active' from the code the return is 'undefined.'

Comment: As expected since there would then be 0 elements with the .active class, which is how it's finding the value.

Comment: Obviously a nav-tab is selected: how do I grab the href?

Comment: Your code already successfully grabs the href